# Safari isn't decoding this AAC+ audio stream

Tags: html, audio, safari, jplayer, aac

I've been working on an HTML5 Live Audio player for an internet radio station I work for. You may recognize it because I did not build it myself. It works fine on my iPhone. However, when I try to play it in safari, chrome and firefox it acts like it's playing but doesn't have any audio.

It's hosted [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.undoing.tv/zen/index.html) for now while I'm working on it.

The stream it's pulling from can be directly linked to at http://1382.live.streamtheworld.com/SAM06AAC156_SC

If you play it in VLC or iTunes it plays just fine.

It's encoded in HE-AAC 64Kbs 44.1KHz Stereo

After a bunch of research I think I've concluded that Safari isn't decoding the stream? I'm lost. It acts the same way in Chrome and Firefox.

I only have basic knowledge of this stuff as it is, but I'm learning. Thanks for your help on this.